# Retrieve msiexec error code from script

Tags: scripting, vbscript, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have 2 problems that I need help with:

1. I need to create a script to get the (error/success) code of an installation with msiexec.
   Any resources, examples about this?
2. If my WIX Custom Action fails how can I return an error code for the installation?
   Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

1. check ERRORLEVEL environment variable
   e.g. (C#) Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ERRORLEVEL")
2. return 3